# JQuery/AJAX to display chat messages dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I'm facing a problem and I need your help to solve it.
Right now I have to display messages under this layout :
[image: http://i.imgur.com/x8jgY95.png]

I am detecting the clicks on the different conversations with Javascript/JQuery, the selected conversation background gets highlighted like on the picture and now I have to display the messages from the selected conversation in the messages container.

Each conversation div have a conversation id in it :

```
<div id="1" class="conversation"></div>
```

I know how to get the messages in the right order with SQL :

```
SELECT text FROM messages WHERE id_conversation=1 ORDER BY date DESC;
```

But how to display them since I can't use php with javascript (right?) ?

I'm using this code to get which conversation got clicked on:

```
$('.conversation').click(function() {
    $('.text').removeClass('highlightedtext');
    $(this).find('.text').addClass('highlightedtext');
    $('.conversation').removeClass('highlightedconversation');
    $(this).addClass('highlightedconversation');
});
```

Resume:

1. I need to display the messages linked to the selected conversation in the messages container using the SQL query
2. I need to clear the messages container when an other conversation is selected, then display the selected conversation again

Comment: if you want to do it without refreshing the page, you have to use `ajax` like `jQuery.post()`, `jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.getJSON()`. please give it a try

Comment: Thank you EhsanT, i used ajax with a JSON array and it works great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything works fine using a JSON encoded php array, i'm using the following Javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'checkmessage.php',
      data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        var text = "";
        var i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
          text += "<div class='msg'>"
          for (j = 0; j < result[i].length; ++j) {
            text += result[i][j];
          }
          text += "</div><br>"
          $('#messagescontainer').append(text);
          text = "";
        }
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
      }
    });
```